# q-binomial Identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Unfortunately I am not able to solve the following problem:
[image]

I tried finding a bijection similar to the prove of this binomial identity: $$\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k} = \binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$$
but I was not able to find one.
I'd really appreciate if someone could give me a hint/tip/solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ be an ${\Bbb F}_q$-vector space of dimension $n$.  Then both expressions count the number of towers of subspaces $V\supset W\supset U$ where $\dim W=m$ and $\dim U=k$.

For the left-hand side, first count the $W$'s in $V$, and then for each $W$ count the $U$'s in $W$.  For the right-hand side, first count the $U$'s in $V$, and then count the number of $W$'s "between" $U$ and $V$.  (You're really counting the number of possibilities for $W/U$ with dimension $m-k$ in the quotient vector space $V/U$, which has dimension $n-k$.)